# Finding no. of cases where $12$ people finished the Marathon

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> $12$ people ($6$ male, $6$ female) run a marathon. Every time a person finishes a marathon, males who finished marathon are more than or equals to females who finished it. How many number of cases in this situation when every $12$ people finished marathon?

I think it should be $N \times 6! \times 6!$, but I have no idea what $N$ should be.

[image]

this picture stands for a same situation but with $4$ males and $4$ females.

each square means male and circle means female.

So the $N$ is $14$ , then the answer (when $4$ males and $4$ females runs marathon instead of $6,6$) should be $14 \times 4! \times 4!$

Answer (score 3):

The answer, for $n$ women and $n$ men, is 
$$n!n!C_n,$$
where $C_n$ is the $n$-th [Catalan Number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) We have
$$C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.$$
It turns out that $C_6=132$.  (By the way, your list was complete: $C_4=14$.)

The linked article has two thorough proofs. One can bypass Catalan numbers, sort of, by noting that the $C_k$ of our problem satisfy the recurrence $C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n C_iC_{n-i}$.